# Chicken stock quantity to substitute for 1 stock cube (knorr)?

Tags: chicken, stock

How much homemade chicken stock should I substitute when recipe calls for a stock cube?  I added 5 litres of water to cover carcass.

Anything else I can do with simmered chicken & veg. It seems a shame to throw them away?

Comment: Use the simmered chicken&veg in a fried/roasted dish, with good spices. Roasting will produce new flavor in place of what it lost to the stock. It's still inferior to "fresh" but not by far.

Answer (score 7):

Per [Knorr](http://www.knorr.ca/product/detail/259436/chicken-cube), you would dissolve one cube in 2 cups of water (500 ml), so you would use 2 cups of homemade stock and deduct 2 cups of liquid from the recipe.

Note that making stock from a single chicken carcass and 5 liters of water seems like a lot of water; you may wish to reduce the resulting stock until you only have a liter or two.

The stock ingredients have pretty much given their all into the stock.  All of the flavors and gelatin should be dissolved in the liquid, and the remaining solid mass is going to be pretty underwhelming.  It is probably best to discard.